# NPM module doesn't work with Webpack 3 but works with vue-cli3 which based on Webpack 4

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, chart.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I'm trying to use the following [ChartJS](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js) plugin: [chartjs-plugin-crosshair](https://github.com/AbelHeinsbroek/chartjs-plugin-crosshair). When I use it within a new VueJS project which was built by using [vue-cli v3.3.0](https://cli.vuejs.org/) everything is working as it should, but when I trying to use it within the legacy VueJS project which utilize Webpack 3 it doesn't work. No errors being thrown, just functionality which it should add to ChartJS was absent.

When I tried to debug the issue and opened [`chartjs-plugin-crosshair/dist/chartjs-plugin-crosshair.js`](https://pastebin.com/9FEndeLe) file which I obviously import from within my project I paid attention that it doesn't have `module.exports = ...` neither `export default ...` and when I rewrote the plugin so it does have export statement it began partially work.
However, functionality which was added by line 21:

```
    Chart$$1.Interaction.modes.interpolate = function(chart, e, options) {
        ...
    }
```

still didn't work till I moved this code inside a VueJS component.

As I understand this plugin uses module dependency which isn't supported by my Webpack configuration, but I couldn't understand which one it uses. Here is a relevant code:

```
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(require('chart.js')) :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['chart.js'], factory) :
    (factory(global.Chart));
}(this, (function (Chart) { 'use strict';
...
})));
```

- **First question** is which module dependency it uses and how I should change my Webpack configuration to cause it work. I didn't share my current `webpack.conf.js` because it's distributed across multiple `dev`, `base` files, but if it's required I will share the whole project after some cleaning.
- **The second question** why functionality added by altering `Chart` object at line 21 as I mentioned above doesn't work. I understand that at some point altered object being overridden, but why and how can I fix it?

This is code of my VueJS component which supposed to use this plugin:

```
<script>
import crosshairPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-crosshair';
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs';
import { CHART_DEFAULTS } from './defaults';
const { reactiveProp } = mixins;

export default ({
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [reactiveProp, CHART_DEFAULTS],
  props: {
    options: Object
  },
  data () {
    return {};
  },
  mounted () {
    this.addPlugin(crosshairPlugin);
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.computedOptions);
  }
});
</script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to require it instead? Also, what is `this.addPlugin`?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Both `const crosshairPlugin = require('chartjs-plugin-crosshair');` and `import ...` returns empty object. Because I use `ChartJS` from `VueJS` I use `vue-chart.js` wrapper and it's `addModule` is part of the API to register external inline plugin https://vue-chartjs.org/api/#addplugin

Answer (score 0):

The example code you gave in the beginning: "I paid attention that it doesn't have module.exports = ... neither export default"

```
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' 
? factory(require('chart.js')) 
: typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['chart.js'], factory) :
    (factory(global.Chart));
}(this, (function (Chart) { 'use strict';
...
})));
```

Above says:

If on the system this code is running has export as an object and module does exist, do factory(require('chart.js')

ELSE

if define equals function and define.amd exists then define(['chart.js'], factory)

AND

if none of the above exist just do factory(global.Chart)

### Did you do:

"npm install vue-chartjs chart.js --save"

or just

"npm install vue-chartjs --save"

Chart.js is a peer-dependency and needed, the last option will not work.

npm install chartjs --save will do the trick I think